# Disable all buttons in an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to disable buttons after they are clicked in Excel 2013.

My code works fine but for just one specific button.

How can apply the same logic to all buttons in a Sheet?

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").OnAction = Empty
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").DrawingObject.Font.ColorIndex = 16
```

Comment: Google loop all controls on sheet.  Often rephrasing the question with what you actually want will give you the insight to google what you need.  You are asking "how to loop through controls on a sheet excel vba" not Disable button clicks,  You need to show some effort also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess this is what you're looking for:

```
Sub Answer()
dim sh as shape
For Each Sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Sh.OnAction = Empty
    Sh.DrawingObject.Font.ColorIndex = 16
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question whether you want pressing Button1 to "disable" all controls on the sheet, or whether you want *each* button to disable itself.

**Button1 disables all controls**

```
Sub Button1_Click
  Dim shp As Shape
  For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
    With shp
      If .Type = msoFormControl Then
        .OnAction = ""
        .DrawingObject.Font.ColorIndex = 16
      End If
    End With
  Next shp
End Sub
```

**Each button disables itself**
Use a common button disabler helper procedure...

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  DisableButton Sheet1, "Button 1"
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()
  DisableButton Sheet1, "Button 2"
End Sub

Sub DisableButton(hostSheet As Worksheet, shapeName As String)
  Dim shp As Shape
  On Error Resume Next
  Set shp = hostSheet.Shapes(shapeName)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not shp Is Nothing Then
    With shp
      If .Type = msoFormControl Then
        .OnAction = ""
        .DrawingObject.Font.ColorIndex = 16
      End If
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Sorry for my unclear question. I have a lot of buttons and I want to disable each button itself, 
it does not matter if his name is button1 , button2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should hide all form control (including buttons) in the worksheet.

```
Dim ws_export As Worksheet 
Dim shp_hide As Shape

 For Each shp_hide In ws_export.Shapes
    If shp_hide.Type = msoFormControl Then shp_hide.Visible = FALSE

 Next shp_hide
```